# Creating dynamic queries for SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, nested, union, sql

I have 2 tables in a DB.

Table2 has values that would be needed for Table1

Example

Table1 has the following fields

Name
FoodColor
FoodSmell
FoodCookingStyle

As we all know certain foods can be cooked in a variety of ways (while producing the same results). One approach is to create a new row for each variation.

Table2 would have data for FoodCookingStyle like
FoodCookingStyle=1 OR FoodCookingStyle=2 OR FoodCookingStyle=3

So the result is I want to create a Query that uses the results from Table2 to produce a SQL Query that would look like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE FoodCookingStyle=1 OR FoodCookingStyle=2 OR FoodCookingStyle=3
```

(only difference is I want to query table2 instead of typing out the expression).

Type of DB being used is SQLite3.

Thank you

---

To clarify what I meant.
I need the output for table2 to be the input for table1

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. If you have a FoodCookingStyle column in Table1 already, what is it you need from Table2 that you can't get querying Table1 alone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit confusing. Is it subqueries you're looking for ? Subquery syntax is along the lines of  `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE FoodCookingStyle IN 
( SELECT FoodCookingStyle FROM Table2 WHERE FoodCookingStyle=1 OR FoodCookingStyle=2 OR FoodCookingStyle=3 )`

Comment: I really need the output to table2 to be the input for table1

Comment: SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE FoodCookingStyle IN (SELECT FoodCookingStyle FROM Table2 WHERE FoodCookingStyle IN (1,2,3))
Similar to miket2e's answer, just that I'm using an IN clause instead of =

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the correction, the 'IN' was what I meant to type too.

Comment: @Arun It sounds good but can you please explain what the WHERE statement means?